# SimpleFacebook isLogin returns true even when I logout from Facebook app on device

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

I have integrated SimpleFacebook on Android in my application. It works most of the times, except for one use-case. Suppose I start my app, and then, log - out from Facebook app on device. Then, I come back to my app, and try to log-in using Facebook SDK. The app is not detecting that I am logged out of Facebook app on the device. The cause for this, is that, SimpleFacebook API isLogin() is returning true.

Is this a known issue? I am using SimpleFacebook and Facebook SDK version 3.5.2.

Comment: You mean that SimpleFacebook always returns true if you login to facebook or not ?

Comment: If first time Facebook is logged in, SimpleFacebook returns true always subsequently. Only if Facebook is logged out on the device, then, first time, before login is invoked, isLogin() returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Facebook issue
You need to clear the Session token cache that is in local memory. So place this before login

```
Session ses = mSimpleFacebook.getSession();
ses.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

*I wonder why the -1 in the question*

Comment: The above API behaves as expected. Additional API in SimpleFacebook to nullify the instance, sessionManager class variables is required.